# Groovy script to stop StreamSets pipeline based on http response

Tags: groovy, streamsets

I want to stop a streamsets pipeline by creating a custom event using Groovy evaluator. I have an http origin stage which gives a json response. I need to have a groovy which reads the json response and create a custom event when final record is reached. I need to write the records to a file till the final record reached. I don’t have a option to create event in http origin stage. Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you add an HTTP Client origin into the pipeline, the default Mode (in HTTP tab of its config) is Streaming, ie the origin will be waiting for more data. Your use case seems to be for Batch mode -- just switch it there in the config.